# node.js http.get chunk not returning correctly structured

Tags: node.js

This might be complicated by running inside of a railwayjs controller(haven't moved to compound yet), don't think so though, don't think there is anything here that railway is interfering with.

I have the following:

```
var http = require('follow-redirects').http;
var https = require('follow-redirects').https;
action('index', function (req,res) {
    var url = decodeURIComponent(request.query.url);
    var resobj;
    var stat;
    var headers;
    http.get(url, function (r) { 
        stat = r.statusCode;
        headers = r.headers;
    r.on('data', function (chunk) {
            resobj += chunk.toString();
        });
        r.on('end', responder);
    });
    function responder(){
    response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': headers["content-type"]
        })
        response.write(resobj);
        response.end();
    }

});
```

request.query.url is from railway, or maybe from express underlying, at any rate it returns correctly. However whenever I run this on various websites I have two problems

1. The text undefined is coming out before anything else, for example before the doctype declaration.
2. The structure of the chunk seems to be off, leading browsers to fix the html (might be caused by the 'undefined' string), this fixing means that elements normally found in the head when rendered end up in the body,

Any ideas about fixing this - also if anyone can show me how to do the above code so that I can get at least as good a result with one of the node phantomjs bridges it would be nice.

Comment: I should specify that this undefined is not found in the first chunk of the webpages I have tested on. those I have tested on are www.metafilter.com, www.google.com, www.cnn.com, www.balloon-juice.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question is about a year old but I landed on it trying to fix a similar problem. Node handles these responses in streams to keep its footprint fairly low. Asking Node to buffer them and trying to concatenate the chucks is more work than necessary. I found that using mikeal's request package is the easiest way to handle responses 'body' https://github.com/mikeal/request

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
    }
})
```